# Find two matching rows in a Pandas DataFrame to calculate value

Tags: python, pandas

I want to find a matching row for another row in a Pandas dataframe. Given this example frame:

```
        name  location   type    year     area    delta
0   building        NY      a    2019    650.3        ?
1   building        NY      b    2019    400.0        ?
2       park        LA      a    2017    890.7        ?
3       lake        SF      b    2007    142.2        ?
4       park        LA      b    2017    333.3        ?
         ...
```

Each row has a matching row, where all values equal - except the "type" and the "area". For example row 0 and 1 match, and 2 and 4, ...

I want to somehow get the matching rows; and write the difference between their areas in their "delta" column (e.g. |650.3 - 400.0| = 250.3 for row 0).

The "delta" column doesn't exist yet, but an empty column could be easily added with `df["Delta"] = 0`. I just don't know how to be able to fill the delta column for ALL rows.

I tried getting a matching row with `df[name = 'building' & location = 'type' ... ~& type = 'a']`; but I can't edit the result I get from that. Maybe I also don't quite understand when I get a copy, and when a reference.

I hope my problem is clear. If not, I am happy to explain further.

Thanks a lot already for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you want [`groupby.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html):

```
df['delta']=( df.groupby(df.columns.difference(['type','area']).tolist())
                .transform('diff').abs() )
print(df)
       name location type  year   area  delta
0  building       NY    a  2019  650.3    NaN
1  building       NY    b  2019  400.0  250.3
2      park       LA    a  2017  890.7    NaN
3      lake       SF    b  2007  142.2    NaN
4      park       LA    b  2017  333.3  557.4
```

If you want to write the difference in both rows of`delta` column:

```
df['delta']=( df.groupby(df.columns.difference(['type','area']).tolist())
                .transform(lambda x: x.diff().bfill()).abs() )
print(df)
       name location type  year   area  delta
0  building       NY    a  2019  650.3  250.3
1  building       NY    b  2019  400.0  250.3
2      park       LA    a  2017  890.7  557.4
3      lake       SF    b  2007  142.2    NaN
4      park       LA    b  2017  333.3  557.4
```

---

**Detail:**

```
df.columns.difference(['type','area']).tolist()
#[*df.columns.difference(['type','area'])] or this

#['location', 'name', 'year'] #Output
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution with `merge`:

```
df['other_type'] = np.where(df['type']=='a', 'b', 'a')
(df.merge(df, 
         left_on=['name','location', 'year', 'type'],
         right_on=['name','location', 'year', 'other_type'],
         suffixes=['','_r'])
   .assign(delta=lambda x: x['area']-x['area_r'])
   .drop(['area_r', 'other_type_r'], axis=1)
)
```